# Limit of sequences: a generalization of $\frac1{n}+\frac1{n+1}+\dots +\frac1{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $x_n \to \xi$, it follows that$$
\left[\frac{x_{pn+q}}{pn+q}+\frac{x_{p(n+1)+q}}{p(n+1)+q}+\dots+\frac{x_{pp'n+q}}{pp'n+q}\right]\to\frac1{p}\xi\log p'$$
where $p, p',$ and $q$ denote given natural numbers.
This result is quite interesting in my opinion, and generalizes the known limit given in the title. How can I prove it?

Comment: Try to prove it first in the case that $p=1$ and $x_n = \xi$ for all $n$.

Comment: And then maybe the squeeze theorem can help right? I think that I have a solution in mind...

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\sum_{k = n}^{p'n}{1 \over pk + q} \to {\ln\left(p'\right) \over p}\ \mbox{as}\ n \to \infty$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes! That's exactly what I wanted to prove. Can you confirm that an application of the squeeze theorem is enough to show the rest?